# error in my registration page in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I am new  in php and in this registration form I am  getting the following error in following code.:

```
1. Notice: Undefined index: gender..
2. Notice: Array to string conversion in the line of mysql query...
```

I have given name to radio button still it is showing undefined index. and second one is array to string conversion in mysql query i am not able to understand what's going wrong. please help me and thank u in advance.

```
    <?php
    include_once 'conn.inc';

     if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
     {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 40000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          $_SESSION['image']=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

          }
      }
      else {
          echo "fail";
      }
        $name=$_POST['txtname'];
        $fname=$_POST['txtfname'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $image=$_FILES['file'];
        $des=$_POST['designation'];
        $job=$_POST['txtjob'];
        $country=$_POST['txtcont'];
        $state=$_POST['txtstate'];
        $city=$_POST['txtcity'];
        $email=$_POST['txtemail'];
        $csatuts=$_POST['contactno'];
        $esatuts=$_POST['email'];
        $contact=$_POST['txtno'];

        $query="insert into tblregistration values('','$name','$fname','$gender','$image','$des','$job','$country','$state','$city','$contact','$csatuts','$email','$esatuts') " or die('error');
        $res= mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_affected_rows())
        {
            $e= "You are successfully registered!!!";
        }
     }
    ?>
```

HTML part

```
<div id="content">
     <div class="box"><div class="heading">Registration</div></div>
     <div class="reg">
     <form action="registration.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px">

            <tr>

                <td><label for="txtname">Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtname" value="Enter your name"  class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><label for="txtfname">Father's Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtfname" value="Enter your father's name" class="tb22" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Gender</label></td>
                <td>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file"  name="file" /></td>
                 <td><img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="./upload/icon3.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Designation</label></td>
                <td><select name="designation" class="tb22">
                    <option value="-1">Select Designation</option>
                    <option value="employed">Employed</option>
                    <option value="selfemployed">Self-Employed</option>
                    <option value="Retired">Retired</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                           <td><label for="txtjob">Title of JOB</label></td>                
                            <td><input type="text" name="txtjob" value="Title of job" class="tb22" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>            
                             <td><label for="txtcont">Country</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="txtcont" class="tb22" value="Enter your Country"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                     <td><label for="txtstate">State</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtstate"  value="Enter your state" class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                     <td><label for="txtcity">City</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtcity" value="Enter your city"  class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtno">Contact No.</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="txtno" value="Enter your no." class="tb22" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <i>private</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="contactno"  value="0" /> &nbsp;<i>public</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="contactno" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtemail">Email</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" name="txtemail" value="Enter your email" class="tb22" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <i>private</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="email"  value="0" />&nbsp;<i>public</i> &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="email" value="1" /></td></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="btnsave" value="submit" class="tb20" />
     <?php if(isset($e))
     { echo "$e";} 

        ?>   
     </form>
```

Comment: You can add a more suitable title to your question!

Comment: Besides uploading any file + SQL injection, this is a duplicate of a very common question

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Nishant i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\wamp\www\website-template-40\website-template-40\registration.php on line 33
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0023 163760 {main}( ) ..\registration.php:0

Comment: thank u nishant but still i am getting error in picture uploading. It is showing 'fail' but i am selecting image of lesser size and ao same format as in condition..

Comment: @PriyankaBhatnagar you are already checking `extension in your `if condition`..no need to put `&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)`.. remove this...

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_WARNING ^ ~E_NOTICE);` before `include_once 'conn.inc';`

Comment: @Anamika error reporting is on.. I think only some improvement is needed in the code..

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `@$_POST`, example

```
$gender= @$_POST['gender']
```

or check if variable is not empty before assigning, example

```
    if(isset($_POST['gender']))
        $gender= $_POST['gender'];
    else
        $gender= 0; //any default value of blank
```

besides that you should take image name as

```
$image=$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

and query should be

```
    $query= "insert into tblregistration values('','$name','$fname','$gender','$image','$des','$job',
                '$country','$state','$city','$contact','$csatuts','$email','$esatuts')" ;

    $res= mysql_query($query) or die('error');
```

Comment: may be `isset` is more reliable than `empty`.. `empty` will only check wether there is value or not.. but what if the `gender` is not posted???

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include_once 'conn.inc';

if (isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 40000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $_SESSION['image'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
else
{
    echo "fail";
}
$name = $_POST['txtname'];
$fname = $_POST['txtfname'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$des = $_POST['designation'];
$job = $_POST['txtjob'];
$country = $_POST['txtcont'];
$state = $_POST['txtstate'];
$city = $_POST['txtcity'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$csatuts = $_POST['contactno'];
$esatuts = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['txtno'];

$query = "insert into tblregistration values('','$name','$fname','$gender','$image','$des','$job','$country','$state','$city','$contact','$csatuts','$email','$esatuts')";

$res = mysql_query($query);
if ($res)
{
    $e = "You are successfully registered!!!";
}
}
?>
```

Registration

```
            <tr>

                <td><label for="txtname">Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtname" value="Enter your name"  class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><label for="txtfname">Father's Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtfname" value="Enter your father's name" class="tb22" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Gender</label></td>
                <td>Male<input type="radio" selected name="gender" value="m"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file"  name="file" /></td>
                <td><img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="./upload/icon3.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Designation</label></td>
                <td><select name="designation" class="tb22">
                        <option value="-1">Select Designation</option>
                        <option value="employed">Employed</option>
                        <option value="selfemployed">Self-Employed</option>
                        <option value="Retired">Retired</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtjob">Title of JOB</label></td>                
                <td><input type="text" name="txtjob" value="Title of job" class="tb22" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>            
                <td><label for="txtcont">Country</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtcont" class="tb22" value="Enter your Country"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td><label for="txtstate">State</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtstate"  value="Enter your state" class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td><label for="txtcity">City</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtcity" value="Enter your city"  class="tb22"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtno">Contact No.</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="txtno" value="Enter your no." class="tb22" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <i>private</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="contactno"  value="0" /> &nbsp;<i>public</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="contactno" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtemail">Email</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" name="txtemail" value="Enter your email" class="tb22" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <i>private</i>&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="email"  value="0" />&nbsp;<i>public</i> &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="email" value="1" /></td></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="btnsave" value="submit" class="tb20" />
        <?php
        if (isset($e))
        {
            echo "$e";
        }
        ?>   
    </form>
```